# Writing big files: Open once, or reopen for every writing event?

Tags: python, memory, file-io

I have to write a lot of data into big tab delimited file with ten-thousands of rows and columns. What would be the better approach:

1. Using `with open(outfile,"w") as x:` at the beginning, then write every long line into the file after it is calculated.
2. Calculate every line and append it right after it is calculated calling `with open(outfile, "a") as x:` again and again for every line and close file after every line.

PS: Is there any disadvantage regarding memory usage of `with open` over `open`?

Comment: Why not profile it and find out?

Comment: Using `with open..` ususally works well for me. You don't have to bother about closing it, an no need to open it everytime as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reopening the same file again and again will obviously take much more time:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python opentest.py
each : 
11.1244959831
once : 
0.124312162399
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ cat opentest.py

def each(data):
    for whatever in data:
        with open("opentest-each.dat", "a") as f:
            f.write(whatever)

def once(data):
    with open("opentest-once.dat", "a") as f:
        for whatever in data:
            f.write(whatever)

def main():
    import timeit

    t1 = timeit.Timer("each(data)", "from opentest import each; data=map(str, range(10000))")
    print "each : "
    print t1.timeit(100)

    t2 = timeit.Timer("once(data)", "from opentest import once; data=map(str, range(10000))")
    print "once : "
    print t2.timeit(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

wrt/ memory usage, using `with open(...)` shouldn't make any noticeable difference (if it makes any difference at all).

Now note that if your code is intented to run as a command-line script, the best solution would be to write to `sys.stdout` and use your shell to redirect `stdout` to a file.